# How does Raptr's "Track gametime manually" work?

Tags: raptr

On [Raptr](http://raptr.com), can I manually track multiple games at once or will it only manually track one at a time? If manually tracking multiple games at once is not possible, which one will be tracked - the first one, or the latest one that I set up for manual tracking?

Will manual tracking stop if I play another game while the manual tracker is "running"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I managed to find the answer to my question ([reference](http://raptr.com/forums/showthread.php?t=16840)):

> ***4.3. Manual Tracking FAQS***
>  Q: What happens if I set more than one game to track at once? A: Nothing, they will all track fine, with
>   no issues. Every game is considered separate from the others, so
>   tracking 2 (or 20, or 2000) at once, even some of them automatically
>   and some manually, will cause no issues. The only thing you shouldn't
>   do is track the exact same game both automatically and manually at the
>   same time.